# Shadows not showing as I intended

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

The shadows in my scene aren't working as I would like. The shadow beneath the shelf is 'blocked out'. I take it Blender is reading the shelf and supports as a single object.

Is there a way to overcome this?

I'm using 2.8 with Eevee

Here is link to Blender file:
[image]

Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Issue fixed:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable "Contact Shadows" on your lights. Select all your area lamps, go in the properties editor, light tab, and in the Shadow panel, hold <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> and check the "Contact Shadows" subpanel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That has added a shadow now, but I'd that full shelf to behave as one object so only a single shad is cast. At the minute it doesn't look very realistic.

Do you have any ideas? Really appreciate your help

Comment: Is there a way to add another image to this post to show problem?

Comment: @Greg3D Just edit your question and post the image there.

Comment: Thanks @RobertGützkow. Ive added the image plus the latest Blender file as a download. Appreciate any help

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "I'd that full shelf to behave as one object so only a single shad is cast". Do you mean you want your object to cast only one shadow? Shadows come from lights sources, if you want one shadow, you need one light, but that wouldn't fit with your scene with all these ceiling lights. If you want harder lights, then reduce your area lights' size, they are actually huge compared to their real size models.

Comment: Thanks @L0Lock. Sorry, yes, I meant "I'd like for the object to cast one shadow". Understand about the single light source and I have amended, yet I'm still encountering an issue with the shadow, highlighted in the last image in the original question. The shadows cast by the shelves are broken, instead of being continuous. Any ideas why?

Comment: This is because of how Eevee manages shadows, there's the "contact shadows" doing the work where volume starts from another (i.e. in corners), and the regular shadows doing the rest. There's a discontinuity between them, which I think you can try to reduce with higher values on the contact shadows' thickness.

Comment: Issue fixed, thanks @L0Lock. Increasing the contact shadows thickness didn't resolve the issue, so I tried increasing the distance of the contact shadows, which has now resolved the issue. Thanks again for your help :)